# No disk to erase in Disk Utility Internet Recovery

Tags: macos, disk-utility, recovery

Earlier today, my MacBook Pro 2013 went to the grey screen of death (folder flashing with the question mark) and now won't boot up. I started internet recovery all fine, but when I went to reinstall OS X, there was no disk to install it to available.

Therefore, I want to the Disk Utility to erase, and do a clean install, except there is only disk0, and as part of that, OS X Base system showing. Total size of these two disks is only 1.28 GB, yet my HD is 256 GB.

Further, all of the options to erase are greyed out for OS X base system, as though I'm not in recovery mode, except I am.

Has my HD died, or do I have other options?

[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: Well, that explains why you get the folder flashing with the question mark... you don't have a Macintosh HD!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet recovery loads from the internet and runs in RAM. Presumably you have more than 1.28GB of RAM. OS X Base System is the base system for recovery, not your internal drive. Based on that, it cannot see your internal drive at all. There's not much you can do if the computer itself can't see the drive. If there's any way you can get this into an Apple Store, that would probably be the easiest solution as I'm sure Apple's technicians could fix this in no time.

On the other hand, if you're comfortable with opening this up and checking for loose wires, then that would probably be my first step (emphasis on MY first step. I wouldn't recommend this to most people).